# Android service not offered for sharing intents

Tags: android, intentfilter

For my application I want to receive a file shared from some other application like the gallery and process it in a background thread. Previously I used an `Activity` for that which worked nicely but made the user leave the application he was working before for no good reason. I tried to switch to an `IntentService`.

In my Android manifest I have this

```
    <service
        android:name=".TestService"
        android:label="Test Image Service"
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

TestService is quite simple

```
public class TestService extends IntentService {
    public TestService() {
        super("TestServiceImageReceiver");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String type = intent.getType();

        Log.d("TestService", type);
    }
}
```

Now I load this on a device, verify the rest of the application is running, go to the gallery, share an image and can't find this service in the "Share Picture via" dialog. Adding the same `intent-filter` to some action makes it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I load this on a device, verify the rest of the application is running, go to the gallery, share an image and can't find this service in the "Share Picture via" dialog

`ACTION_SEND` is an activity action, for use with `startActivity()`. A service will not work.

> Previously I used an Activity for that which worked nicely but made the user leave the application he was working before for no good reason.

Then use a `Theme.NoDisplay` activity that starts your `IntentService` from its `onCreate()`, then calls `finish()`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, found it now in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html Quote: "These are the current standard actions that Intent defines for launching activities (usually through startActivity(Intent)."

Comment: @johannes: Note that you probably still want to do *something* from a UI standpoint, such as show a `Toast`, just to let the user know you are handling the request.